# VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation VS class VNClassificationObservation

Tags: ios, swift, coreml

I was researching on **CoreML** to create Machine learning app. I was reading the apple Documentation and found this two class **VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation** and **VNClassificationObservation**. After reading documentation i was confused on what kind of model should i use these class. Also apple documentation provide different model such as **mobileNet, SqueezeNet, Places205-GoogLeNet, ResNet50 and VGG16**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `VNClassificationObservation` is returned when the model is a classifier. It now outputs a dictionary of `[String: Double]` that has the probability score for every class in the model. The models you listed are all classifiers.

The `VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation` is returned when the model is not a classifier. Instead of a dictionary, such models usually output an `MLMultiArray` object. You willhave to do your own post-processing to interpret the data from this kind of output.

Comment: thank you for replay. In my research on Machine Learning in  iOS. i found your CoreMLHelper. i read CoreMLHelper documentation and also created prediction app with your library. I have a dought can't i use Non-maximum suppression (NMS) to create bounding box in classification observations

Comment: NMS doesn't create bounding boxes, it only keeps the best ones. If you have a classifier output, you don't get bounding box predictions. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: i was using ResNet50 model to classify object and i thought of adding box in that object which classifies with confidence > 0.75.

Comment: i create object prediction app using mobile Net model, i also use you coreMLHelper. when my app start predicting objects such as person or laptop more then one bounding box appears. Is that a bug in my code or its model problem. My app does not predict accurately. i wanted my object detection to be accurate.

Comment: Those questions are way too broad for Stack Overflow. ;-) But yes, usually multiple bounding boxes appear for each object.